# how to convert iso code into languages in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

how to convert iso code into languages in python

Comment: and what is your current output?

Answer (score 1):

you can use this https://pypi.org/project/iso-language-codes/

just install with `pip install iso-language-codes`

and you can use like this:

```
from iso_language_codes import *
print(language_name("It"));
```

for an array you can do a for and it's done

Comment: actually we have file with extension joblib in that we havw sample input like ['en','en','ar'...........] like this i want it should be convert into english

Comment: @TechGuy You should edit the question to add this information as it is not very clear